# Why are my python scripts not updating even though that are saved?

Tags: python, import, permissions, directory, save

Fair warning, I'm a relatively inexperienced programmer, so my terminology may not be perfect.

First off, I cloned a repository from Github that has a directory with the following structure:

```
main  
   -> dir1  
      -> script1.py  
   -> dir2
      -> script2.py
```

Where foo contains a class called "Class" that implements a method foo(), which is called in script2.py.

```
script1.py
-------------------
class Class:
    def __init__(self):
      ...
    def foo(self):
      ...
```

...

```
script2.py
------------------------
    from dir1 import Class
    test = Class()
    print(dir(test))
```

This works as anticipated and prints out all the methods of Class, including foo.

The real issue is that no matter how I change script1.py, while the text appears to have saved, if I run script2.py (python script2.py), dir(test) always produced the same result.

For example, if I were to remove the foo method from script1 and replace it with a bar() method, the file will be saved correctly, but when I run script2, dir(test) will still show foo among the methods of Class, and will not have bar displayed.
Also test.foo() would work, but test.bar() wouldn't even though foo isn't a method of class anymore and bar is.

What I've done so far:

- Clone the repository again
- chmod -R 777 main  before making any changes
- I've added the changes on git, but it has had no change to the functionality of script2
- I've used multiple text editors, including gedit, emacs, nano, and Geany, but none of them have produced different results

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04LTS and I've never experienced this issue before.

Please let me know if there is any other information I should provide or if I should retry something.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `*.pyc` files?

Comment: Just tried that, no dice.

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` in either of these directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your directory structure.

If you have the main directory, i.e. the repo you cloned, let's call it `main_repo`, and a script `script1.py`, and you want to import stuff from `script2.py` in another folder, it should look like

`main_repo
   --> script1.py
   --> other_folder
       --> script2.py`

And then at the top of `script1.py`, write `from other_folder import ClassName` where `ClassName` is located in `script2.py`